# How to update a BIOS without Vista?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, bios, updates

I'm attempting to install an OS on a Compaq Presario SR5113WM. I'm having trouble boot from CD with it, so I figured I would try a BIOS update.

Well, I went to the compaq update page and the BIOS update is for Vista only. This computer does not have Vista though, it has XP.

Any ideas on how to spoof the update to think it's in Vista or another way to update this BIOS?

Comment: what motherboard do you have?

Comment: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=pv-66758-1&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=3443509&os=2093&lang=en is the link for the BIOS update, I can't find a manufacturer, only a model number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can boot off a live vista dvd?

http://www.propeller.com/story/2008/09/08/create-live-xp-or-vista-cddvdusb-easily/

oops just realised, you are having trouble booting from cd. maybe the usb option works for you

good luck

Comment: 404 error for that page..

Comment: Odd. I tried it just now and it works for me. Google for vista live dvd  - there are lots of hits

Comment: I mean, when I click the link where it says "to read the full article" it gives a 404.. and I don't have a copy of vista